# Matching users based on a series of questions

Tags: algorithms, math

I'm trying to figure out a way to match users based on specific personality traits. Each trait will have its own category.

I figure in my user table I'll add a column for each category:

```
id    name    cat1    cat2    cat3
1     Sean    ?       ?       ?
2     Other   ?       ?       ?
```

Let's say I ask each user 3 questions in each category. For each question, you can answer one of the following: `No, Maybe, Yes` How would I calculate one number based off the answers in those 3 questions that would hold a value I can compare other users to?

I was thinking having some sort of weight. Like:

```
No    -> 0
Maybe -> 1
Yes   -> 2
```

Then doing some sort of meaningful calculation. I want to end up with something like this so I can query the users and find who matches close:

```
id    name    cat1    cat2    cat3
1     Sean    4       5       1
2     Other   1       2       5
```

In the situation above, the users don't really match. I'd want to match with someone with a +1 or -1 of my score in each category.

I'm not a math guy so I'm just looking for some ideas to get me started.

Comment: So why doesn't the solution you've tried work? Also, how do you get from (0,1,2) -> 4? What does that imply? If a category indicates a personality trait, why isn't it Boolean? Does the number represent a fuzzy membership? If so, what is the scale (4/5 seems really low)? I think the problem needs to be fleshed out a bit more before approaching the solution.

Comment: @SteveEvers My example wasn't suppose to actually calculate. I was just looking for some ideas to point me in the right direction. The 4 would have been calculated based on adding the weight of the 3 questions in a specific category.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [Euclidean Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), but that's just me.

If you had only 2 categories you could call them X and Y.  Then your problem would be simply a matter of computing the distance between two points.

If you had 3 categories, (X, Y, Z) then you'd need to calculate the distance in 3 dimensions.

According to Wikipedia the general formula is
[image: Euclidean Distance formula]

A match is "close" if the distance between the two is small.

You should be able to compute distance as

```
dist = sqrt( (user1.cat1 - user2.cat1)^2 + (user1.cat2 - user2.cat2)^2 ...)
```

Comment: Thanks! And how do you suppose I actually get the group values for cat1, cat2, etc. Any ideas?

Comment: @SeanWM - There's not enough info in this question to answer how you'd collect the group values for cat1 etc.  You may want to post that as a new question.